# Unable to update label in update panel from user control ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, refresh, code-behind

My code is as follows.

```
  <div class="table">
       <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="labelPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional"  >
           <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="Cost"></asp:Label>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>

      <uc1:ucPartsListing ID="ucPartsListing" runat="server" />

  </div>
```

Now the usercontrol ucPartsListing itself has 2 update panels. There is an event fired from the user control to parent aspx for some conditions. 
In that event, I am trying to set the label value which is present in aspx file. I am calling update manually from code-behind. **Yet it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong ?**

```
 public partial class PartsEnquiry : BaseAuthPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucPartsListing.OnQuotePartsItemSelect += new ascx.ucPartsListing.QuotePartsItemEventHandler(ucPartsListing_OnQuotePartsItemSelect);
    }

    void ucPartsListing_OnQuotePartsItemSelect(string price)
    {
        Cost.Text = price;  //This is not working !

        labelPanel.Update();
    }
```

Comment: try setting the div to runat="server"

Comment: Are you trying to change the text in the `Cost` label from an updatepanel inside the `ucPartsListing` user control?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on your "void ucPartsListing_OnQuotePartsItemSelect(string price)" method and see if it gets hit at all.
I'm not sure what the user control is that you are using, but whatever control it is that is supposed to fire the event, try setting its AutoPostBack property to True.

Comment: Yes it hits the breakpoint.. But doesn't display ! The event if fired in code behind of the user control so no question of AutoPostBack here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck with your current structure.

When the UpdatePanel inside you user control is fired in the browser, it will update the part of the page that is inside itself. You cannot update controls that are outside of the executing UpdatePanel.

Manually calling the `Update()` method on the outer UpdatePanel will not help since on the client it is still one of the inner UpdatePanels that is receiving the output back and updating the html tree.

To get it to work you will have to somehow trigger the outer UpdatePanel which will be able to update the Cost label.

Comment: How can I trigger the outer update panel? I tried using some Asynctriggers but nothing works !